# Chuck replacement - corded BOSCH PSB500 re

Tags: drill

I've got a corded Bosch PSB 500 re and want to replace the existing chuck with a keyless one, please can anyone advise me as to which one I need to buy. It would be very easy for me to buy the wrong one!!
Cheers in advance

Comment: Take the existing one off and that will show you the fitting / thread for the replacement.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your title since you want to replace the chuck itself, not the chuck key.

Answer (score 1):

Dismount the current chuck, measure the diameter and thread count of the shaft, order something based on that; if it doesn't fit return it for credit and try another.

It may be worth taking the old chuck to your local hardware store and trying various sizes of English and Metric bolts as one way to be sure what size is needed. They may also have gauges which can be used to check this. That would greatly increase your odds of getting the right part in the first attempt.

Note that there may be an alternative approach: rubber grips used to be available which could be stretched over a keyed chuck to permit keyless operation. One of my old drills has this adaptation; it works fine, as long as I'm a bit careful to keep my hand clear of the still-exposed chuck teeth.